# Blue Jalappeno Order Export - How do you modify the csv export file?

Tags: orders, extensions, magento-1.6, csv, export

**(I am not 100% sure that this is the extension but I think so - it is in *Community/Webshopapps/ordermanager* and looks like the most likely extension listed at http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer/WebShopApps)**

I have been asked to remove a line break in one column of the csv file that is exported by Blue Jalappeno Order Export. Some of the "Shipping Street" entries have a line break so that the street address looks like this:

"**Appartment 3**

**6 Main St**"

instead of "**Appartment 3 6 Main St**"

The client is unable to do whatever it is he is trying to do with this csv because of the line break so I want to replace it with a space or a dash. It will be done by a cron job so a simple find/replace on the csv wont work.

I have tried the following:

```
$file = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' - ', $file);
```

in the switch in *Webshopapps_Ordermanager_Sales_Order_ExportController*

```
$order = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' - ', $order);
```

in the foreach loop in *Webshopapps_Ordermanager_Model_Export_Csv::exportOrders($orders)*

Has anyone any experience with this extension? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the check and replace at a lower level.

Have a look in Model/Export/Csv.php and you'll see where it gets the billing and shipping address street. From memory it calls out to a function in Abstractcsv.php to format this. You could modify in the function in Abstractcsv.php to remove any line breaks or do this replace within CSV.php